# iOS CNN Convolution Edgemode

Tags: ios, ios10, metal

So I've been experimenting with CNNs on iOS using the new iOS 10 APIs, and I'm not sure why I'm getting the following results.

So I initialize a plain `MPSCNNConvolution` class with a weight array of 1.0 and a bias array of 0.0, and kernel width and height of 3. For testing I'm using only a single feature channel. I'm setting the `MPSImageEdgeMode` to

```
convolution.edgeMode = .clamp
```

which, according to the [iOS Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/metalperformanceshaders/mpsimageedgemode) should do the following

> Out-of-bound pixels are clamped to the nearest edge pixel.

However, forwarding a texture filled with 1.0s, I get the following result:

```
4  6  4
6  9  6
4  6  4
```

which is exactly the same as leaving the edgeMode parameter to its default value `.zero` - so apparently for the top-left corner (0/0), only the values (0/0), (1/0), (1/1) and (0/1) are considered, and the remaining 5 out-of-bounds values are zero rather then the clamped 1 I expected.

Shouldn't the `.clamp` parameter result in the following?

```
9  9  9
9  9  9
9  9  9
```

Is the expected behaviour, or is there something I'm not considering here?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds right to me. I would try it again with a newer OS. If the problem persists, file a bug.

Comment: Ah, the edge mode for the convolution is hard coded to zero. We haven't seen any examples in common CNN frameworks that use anything else.

Comment: Great to know thanks :)